# Need to group Pocketbase collection by year

Tags: sveltekit, pocketbase

I'm using sveltekit and pocketbase and have a collection named `competitionResults`
[image: competitionResults table]

I need to make a page that displays the results of every year in year groups.
E.g. it should looks something like this.

```
2024
Competition X - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up
Competition Y - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up
Competition Z - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up

2023
Competition X - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up
Competition Y - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up
Competition Z - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up

2022
Competition X - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up
Competition Y - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up
Competition Z - William Winner - Ricky Runner Up
```

I've tried to figure out how to group things but I don't understand the docs.